# Cassandra 3.10 debug.log contains frequent "FailureDetector.java:457 - Ignoring interval time of..."

Tags: cassandra

The debug.log files for one of our Cassandra 3.10 clusters has frequent messages similar to “FailureDetector.java:457 - Ignoring interval time of…”

The messages appear even if the cluster is idle.    I see the messages at a rate of about 1 per second on each node of this 6 node cluster (3 nodes each in two data centers).

Can someone tell me what causes the messages and if they are something to be concerned about?

We have a couple of other small clusters supporting the same application (different environments) and I see this message much less often (days apart).

Comment: whats the number? how many ns?

Comment: Below are two typical examples.   I picked a low one and a high one.

Ignoring interval time of 2000253625
Ignoring interval time of 3000692946

Comment: any clock drift between nodes?

Comment: Clock is correct to within ~30 ms between the nodes.   I did learn that these messages started the same day we upgraded to Cassandra 3.10 so perhaps the logging is more verbose with regard to "interval times" in this version.   That wouldn't explain why I don't see it in the other clusters which were also upgraded to 3.10.

Comment: Getting the same message... Any udates?

Answer (score 2):

The `FailureDetector` is responsible of deciding if a node is considered UP or DOWN.

> The gossip process tracks state from other nodes both directly (nodes
>   gossiping directly to it) and indirectly (nodes communicated about
>   secondhand, third-hand, and so on). Rather than have a fixed threshold
>   for marking failing nodes, Cassandra uses an accrual detection
>   mechanism to calculate a per-node threshold that takes into account
>   network performance, workload, and historical conditions. During
>   gossip exchanges, every node maintains a sliding window of
>   inter-arrival times of gossip messages from other nodes in the
>   cluster.

[Here](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/8b3a60b9a7dbefeecc06bace617279612ec7092d/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/gms/FailureDetector.java#L450-L474) you can find the source code, which gives you the log message. It is set to DEBUG level because they may be helpful in tracking down the actual issue causing the latency, but don't indicate a problem on their own.

In other words: your node measures the acknowledgement latency for each gossip message sent to the other nodes e.g: `X nanosec for IP address1, Z nanosec for IP address2, etc.` If either`X` or `Y` is above the expected 2 sec threshold as stated in `MAX_INTERVAL_IN_NANO`, it will get reported.

Problems, which can cause this log message:

- Huge load on the node(s): e.g too many large partitions
- High pressure: e.g. too many queries in sort period of time
- Bad network connection

The extra FailureDetector logging was added with this:
Expose phi values from failure detector via JMX and tweak debug
   and trace logging ([CASSANDRA-9526](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9526?attachmentOrder=desc))

and also I found this open issue, might be related to your problem:
The failure detector becomes more sensitive when the network is flakey([CASSANDRA-9536](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9536))

Also I find [this](http://www.cooldoger.com/2016/10/cassandra-gossip-and-failure-detection.html) article about Gossiping and Failure Detection very useful.