# Cassandra nodetool repair is getting stuck sometimes

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am running `nodetool repair -pr -full my_ks my_tbl` in our Cassandra cluster(has two DCs).
It sometimes hangs with below debug logs. It works after restarting the Cassandra process. Any hints on the root cause of this issue?

```
DEBUG [GossipStage:1] 2020-07-13 14:04:22,818 FailureDetector.java:456 - Ignoring interval time of 2571566434 for /10.22.38.223
DEBUG [GossipStage:1] 2020-07-13 14:04:22,818 FailureDetector.java:456 - Ignoring interval time of 2495429260 for /10.22.38.26
DEBUG [GossipStage:1] 2020-07-13 14:04:22,818 FailureDetector.java:456 - Ignoring interval time of 2571592685 for /10.32.146.85
INFO  [Thread-181] 2020-07-13 14:04:22,900 RepairRunnable.java:125 - Starting repair command #2, repairing keyspace my_ks with repair options (parallelism: parallel, primary range: true, incremental: false, job threads: 1, ColumnFamilies: [my_tbl], dataCenters: [], hosts: [], # of ranges: 256)
INFO  [HANDSHAKE-/10.32.146.85] 2020-07-13 14:04:23,460 OutboundTcpConnection.java:515 - Handshaking version with /10.32.146.85
DEBUG [GossipStage:1] 2020-07-13 14:04:23,716 FailureDetector.java:456 - Ignoring interval time of 2000838464 for /10.22.38.27
DEBUG [GossipStage:1] 2020-07-13 14:04:23,716 FailureDetector.java:456 - Ignoring interval time of 2000923736 for /10.22.38.68
DEBUG [GossipStage:1] 2020-07-13 14:04:23,815 FailureDetector.java:456 - Ignoring interval time of 2100571952 for /10.32.253.232
DEBUG [GossipStage:1] 2020-07-13 14:04:25,247 FailureDetector.java:456 - Ignoring interval time of 2429005356 for /10.32.144.198
```

I am using Cassandra 3.9.

Edit: I see below logs with trace enabled:

```
INFO  [HANDSHAKE-/10.32.168.76] 2020-07-18 02:12:41,253 OutboundTcpConnection.java:515 - Handshaking version with /10.32.168.76
INFO  [HANDSHAKE-/10.32.142.195] 2020-07-18 02:12:42,260 OutboundTcpConnection.java:515 - Handshaking version with /10.32.142.195
INFO  [HANDSHAKE-/10.32.144.198] 2020-07-18 02:12:42,260 OutboundTcpConnection.java:515 - Handshaking version with /10.32.144.198
ERROR [RepairTracePolling] 2020-07-18 02:12:45,836 CassandraDaemon.java:226 - Exception in thread Thread[RepairTracePolling,5,RMI Runtime]
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Operation timed out - received only 0 responses.
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.ReadCallback.awaitResults(ReadCallback.java:132) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.ReadCallback.get(ReadCallback.java:137) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.AbstractReadExecutor.get(AbstractReadExecutor.java:145) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$SinglePartitionReadLifecycle.awaitResultsAndRetryOnDigestMismatch(StorageProxy.java:1718) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy.fetchRows(StorageProxy.java:1667) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy.readRegular(StorageProxy.java:1608) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy.read(StorageProxy.java:1527) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SinglePartitionReadCommand$Group.execute(SinglePartitionReadCommand.java:975) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.SelectStatement.execute(SelectStatement.java:271) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.SelectStatement.execute(SelectStatement.java:232) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.repair.RepairRunnable$4.runMayThrow(RepairRunnable.java:412) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
```

Comment: What is the size of the table? and How many nodes in your cluster?

Comment: 30 nodes in the cluster(15 in each DC). The table sizes are close to 1 to 2 TB.

Comment: Do you also see these FailureDetector pauses when you are not running repairs? I would investigate and see if you can track where these pauses are coming from. These are an indicator that your nodes are pausing, for example due to heavy load or long gc pauses. You can also see this if the clocks are out of sync. Check in system.log what precedes the FailureDetector pauses. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44790873/cassandra-3-10-debug-log-contains-frequent-failuredetector-java457-ignoring

Comment: @bswynn, thanks. I see FailureDetector even when repair is not run. I just checked date in the nodes, clocks are in sync. The FailureDetector logs are seen when there are not many reads. Any other hints to investigate this further? Thanks

Comment: I see messages like "DEBUG [GossipStage:1] 2020-07-15 09:04:24,882 FailureDetector.java:456 - Ignoring interval time of 2770245405 for /10.32.213.247" happening in all nodes continuously.

Comment: these are quite long pauses, close to 3 seconds, check if they come from GC pauses and/or current workload.

Comment: I am not seeing GC pause logs.  Is there nodetool command to check/analyze these?

Comment: I also see "INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2020-07-15 13:07:31,832 IndexSummaryRedistribution.java:75 - Redistributing index summarie" sometimes without any changes to the cluster